# Create element with unique names

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following scenario:

There will be n number of the following tags within my root document.

```
<imagelist>
...
<imgp-src>0020104314-01-1.jpg</imgp-src>
<img-src>0020104314-01-2.jpg</img-src>
<img-src>0020104314-01-3.jpg</img-src>
<imgp-src>0020104314-01-4.jpg</imgp-src>
...
</imagelist>
```

I need to end up with the following, regardless of the source tag (img or imgp)

```
<img_url1>0020104314-01-1.jpg</img_url1>
<img_url2>0020104314-01-2.jpg</img_url2>
<img_url3>0020104314-01-3.jpg</img_url3>
<img_url4>0020104314-01-4.jpg</img_url4>
```

I've tried using a for-each loop with the position function to create the new elements.  I've failed at every attempt.

Notice that the tag can start with either img or imgp.
I need to name the resulting  elements with a sequential identifier.
I can rename the value, but can't seem to get the element renamed.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

I apologize in advance if this is a recurring question.  I thought I had seen this answered before but can't seem to locate the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need unique tag names? That's highly non-idiomatic for XML. The idiomatic way would be `<img_url id="1">url</img_url>` where the `id=` attribute increments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you strip the spaces you can use `position()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="imgp-src | img-src">
        <xsl:element name="img_url{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes you have no other elements in `imagelist`. If you do, they will be counted as well and your numbering will be different. It's safer using `<xsl:number>` since you can choose exactly the nodes you want to count (and don't have to use `strip-space`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="imgp-src | img-src">
        <xsl:variable name="number">
            <xsl:number count="imgp-src | img-src"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="img_url{$number}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's not so much a matter of stripping the spaces, as starting in the middle. And (as a result) your output lacks a root element too.

Answer (score 2):

Use an approach like

```
<xsl:template match="imagelist">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="imagelist/*">
  <xsl:element name="img_url{position()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I believe the output XML needs to have a root element.

Comment: Well the requested result sample in the question does not show one and XSLT allows you to output a fragment so I intentionally did not map the `imagelist` to a result element. If needed that can be done in the template by wrapping the `apply-templates`: `<xsl:template match="imagelist"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.